# Wordpress/MySQL -> get post ids together with a count of total posts written by an author of a given post

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In my Wordpress setup, each post has a post meta attached with meta_key=visitor_tracking_visitor_id, which is the post author id.

I'm trying to pull a list of posts from the Wordpress wp_posts table, together with a count of posts with status=publish for that given author id.

**Tables**

*wp_posts*

id|post_title|post_content|post_status ("publish" or "trash")

*wp_postmeta*

post_id (to join with wp_posts' id)|meta_key|meta_value

when meta_key=visitor_tracking_visitor_id the meta_value holds the author id

**Example expected result:**

|id|meta_value(author id)|count_of_posts_by_that_meta_value|

|1|1234|10|

|2|1234|10|

|3|5678|4|

**I know how to pull the post info together with the author's id:**

```
SELECT `id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, `post_status`, `meta_value` FROM `wp_posts`
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON `id` = `post_id`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND `post_status` in ('trash','publish') AND `meta_key` = 'visitor_tracking_visitor_id'
```

How would I pull another field with the count of author's published posts using only SQL (without Wordpress functions)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In the absence of a data set, an expected result set's about as useful as a chocolate teapot

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating post meta for something that is already available in every post? Just get the author ID for the post get_the_author_id()

If you want lo list post links from an author, in the loop you can use
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link

To get author or users post count you can use
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts

Comment: Hi topdown, I use a custom ids because posts are not added in a standard way on my site where each user has a WP account. Also, I need to export the data from a database, without using Wordpress functions. It is meant to be used for an analysis with an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use SQL for this:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'visitor_tracking_visitor_id',
    'meta_value_num' => 76,  // The "author" ID,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$count = $query->found_posts;
```

Read more about [`WP_Query` in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties).